# NameError: name 'Pkg' is not defined

Tags: julia, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, julia-jump, ijulia-notebook

In the `IJulia` Notebook I'm trying to add the packages, but I'm getting the error:

```
NameError: name 'Pkg' is not defined
```

Comment: You may running Python, not Julia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python was wrongly selected instead of Julia in Jupyter:
[image]

Here's what happens in Julia:
[image]

And here's what happens in Python:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me I had a very similar error, and apparently you have to define Pkg if you're installing this for the first time. Just enter

```
using Pkg
```

It looks like in your case the issue was you were using python but this is a fix for another case where you get this exact same error.